# How to confine mouse to a specific monitor on a multi-monitor system?

Tags: python, qt, pyside

I have a multi-monitor system, running two Python3.x Qt applications (PySide). I successfully designated which application is to run on which monitor. One application (and thus one monitor) is a user input terminal (basically a kiosk), while the other application (and thus the other monitor) is used solely for displaying information.

How can I confine the mouse to the kiosk monitor? I know I can 'disable' the second application such that mouse and keyboard events are ignored, but I'd really rather confine the actual mouse movements to the first monitor.

Is this something that has to make use of low-level Windows (Windows 7) functions, or can I implement something in Python within my applications to handle it?

Any input or guidance here would be much appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: If you want a solution that is more of a hack than anything it would be pretty easy to write a script to check the mouse coordinates constantly and make sure they're in the range you want, and if not instantly move the mouse back in. So the mouse would never cross the border. Just not the most elegant solution.

Comment: I had considered this John, and my have to go down that route if a more elegant solution isn't readily available. Thanks!

Comment: If you don't end up finding anything, I have a script that I already had written to keep the mouse on the left side of the screen, all you would have to do is modify the lowerBound and upperBound variables with your x values: http://pastebin.com/sWtFmmeL

Comment: @John Dorian Your link doesn't work now. It would be nice if you posted your code as an answer.

Comment: @PavelStrakhov It seems pastebin deleted it, I'll post it as an answer for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: originally postesd this answer as a response to a comment asking for some code I already happened to have written that was not in python but accomplished the goal. That script is farther down, here is a python script that only works on windows but will perform the same function using `win32api`.

```
import win32api

# set these to whatever you want
xMin = 300
xMax = 800

running = True
while running:
        x, y = win32api.GetCursorPos()
        if x < xMin:
                win32api.SetCursorPos((xMin,y))
        elif x > xMax:
                win32api.SetCursorPos((xMax,y))
```

Posting for @PavelStrakhov. Here's a java script that will keep the cursor within a certain range of x coordinates (cross platform).

To run it save the below code as `mouseWatcher.java`, run `$ javac mouseWatcher.java`, and then running `$ java mouseWatcher` will start it.

**Be careful though.** If you run this and don't know how to stop it without your mouse and your set range doesn't allow you to move your mouse where you need to, you won't be able to stop it. :-)

```
/* to control the mouse */
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;

/* to get the mouse position */
import java.awt.MouseInfo;

public class mouseWatcher {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /* the minimum and maximum x positions the cursor is allowed at */
        int xMin = 200;
        int xMax = 800;

        /* repeat forever */
        boolean running = true;
        while (running) {
            /* get the current cursor position */           
            int[] position = cursorGetPos();

            /* if they try to move it to the left of the acceptable area */
            if (position[0] < xMin)
                /* move the cursor the left most acceptable point */
                mouseMove(xMin, position[1]);

            /* if they try to move it to the right of the acceptable area */
            else if (position[0] > xMax)
                /* move the cursor to the right most acceptable point */
                mouseMove(xMax, position[1]);
        }
    }

    private static void mouseMove( int x, int y) {
        try {
            Robot r = new Robot();
            r.mouseMove(x, y);
        } catch (AWTException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    private static int[] cursorGetPos() {
        int X = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x; 
        int Y = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().y; 
        int[] coords = {X,Y};
        return coords;
    }

    private static void sleep( int milliseconds ) {
        try {
            Robot r = new Robot();
            r.delay(milliseconds);
        } catch(AWTException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that John. I've had a play around with this general concept, and it looks like it should be fairly simple to implement. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, hope it's useful!